# How we can store edit text values inside hashmap onTextChangedListner

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I am using expandable list view where each one of the child layout has one edit text. I am triggering **setOnFocusChangeListener** for each one of the text box's to prevent the data loss.

But I observed that the text I have entered is storing into the hashmap only when edit text cursor moves next. But I need to store the entered text while typing itself,something like **onKeyUp**.

**Note :** I have also tried Text Watchers but it is not working as expected

**Code**

```
public Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

 ViewHolder holder;

 Map<String, String> item = (Map<String, String>) getChild(i, i1);
 String key = item.get("item_code");

 if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.editText = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecordComment);
        view.setTag(holder);
 } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 }


 holder.editText.setText(mapping.get(key));

 /*
 holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                mapping.put(key, holder.editText.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }); 
   */


   holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                   mapping.put(key, holder.editText.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });


    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    protected EditText editText;
}
```

Problem with above code is if I enter text in a textbox1 of parent1 same text is getting replicated in any one of the textboxs of parent2.

It will be great help if someone suggest me how I can achive this.

Comment: Create a list having value of edittext as a model, and update the value of model at textchange method, and set data using this list in viewholder,

Comment: Thanks for quick response Akash.. Can you give me some sample code references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int viewPosition, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

     ViewHolder holder;

     Map<String, String> item = (Map<String, String>) getChild(i, i1);
     String key = item.get("item_code");

   //  if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.editText = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecordComment);
  //          view.setTag(holder);
   //  } else {
   //         holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
   //  }


     holder.editText.setText(mapping.get(viewPosition));

     /*
     holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    mapping.put(viewPosition, holder.editText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }); 
       */


       holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                       mapping.put(viewPosition, holder.editText.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        protected EditText editText;
    }
```

Comment: I can't set value based on parent viewposition because one parent view can have more than one edittexts.

Comment: And also it will not solve this problem -- if I enter text in a textbox1 of parent1 same text is getting replicated in any one of the textboxs of parent2.

Comment: With Hash Map only key can't be duplicate but value can be duplicate.

Comment: Not working..   whatever value I am entering inside the 1st edit text reflecting to all edit texts

Comment: No.. all are different.. When I scroll the mobile screen same value is replicating to all edit texts

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prateek.. It worked.. Can you explain me what I did wrong.

Comment: it was issue with your view holder object. Now its creating different object for every row. but previously it was taking only one object of ViewHolder class. Thats why you were getting issue with same text set to every edit text.